# Azure API Management only output properties defined in the OpenAPI spec

Tags: azure-api-management

Is it possible to only output the properties in a response on APIM that are defined in the openapi spec uploaded in APIM and not the full response that comes from the backend server?

Our backend API has a response object with 3 properties: FirstName, LastName and BirthDay. On Azure API management we added the openapi spec with a schema definition with only FirstName and LastName, so the BirthDay would not be exposed or leaked. But, when calling the API over APIM, the BirthDay property is available in the response.

There is a validate-content policy but we don't want to block the whole response, we only want to block the properties that are not defined in the openapi schema definition on APIM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer to [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/policies/filter-response-content#policy) to remove the property BirthDay in the response.

```
<outbound>
    <base />
    <choose>
      <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 200 && context.Product.Name.Equals("Starter"))">
        <set-body>
          @{
            var response = context.Response.Body.As<JObject>();
            response.Property ("BirthDay").Remove ();
            return response.ToString();
          }
    </set-body>
      </when>
    </choose>    
  </outbound>
```

Comment: that should mean that we need to create a policy for each operation and manually map the properties from the openapi definition. Isn't there an automated way to map properties to the openapi spec?

Comment: for apim, it seems the only way to manage the response. if you'd like a simple configuration, maybe you need to modify the api itself...